# String char handling: How can I combine a post-processing loop into the primary loop?

Tags: c, string, loops

Here is the question that i am trying to solve but can't figure out an easier way :-

Write a function squeez that deletes each character in s1 that matches any character in the string s2.

What I have done so far is the following code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char *mysqueeze(char *a, char *b);
int main(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    char s1[100] = "krishna";
    char s2[100] = "kareem";
    char real[100];
    char *t = mysqueeze(s1,s2);
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(t); i++)  //1
        if (t[i] != '*')
    real[j++] = t[i];
    real[j] = '\0';        //4

    printf("%s\n", real);
}

char *mysqueeze(char *a, char *b)
{
    int i = 0, k;
    do
    {
        k = 0;
        while (b[k] != '\0')
        {
            if (a[i] == b[k]) {
                a[i] = '*';
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (a[i]);
    return a;
}
```

How can I improve upon this code?How can I move 1 through 4 to the loop part of the code?

Comment: Use a mark different of 'p'. Perhaps a symbol like '*'.

Comment: Take a look at the standard library functions strspn() and strcspn().

Comment: Keep two indexes, one for the character you're looking at, one for the place you'll copy to if the character you're looking at isn't in the reject list.  Initially, the two indexes will be the same, zero.  For each character in the string, if it is not in the reject list, copy it to the current copy-to location and increment the copy-to index.  Increment the looking-at index.  Repeat until EOS.  Add null terminator to copy-to location.

Comment: 1. Spell your function names correctly; 2. Don't use `strlen()` in loop conditions; 3. Don't use variable names like `a` and `b` except as generic loop counters; 4. Don't compare signed and unsigned integers; 5. Indent your code properly, and use braces even for one line loops or conditionals; 6. Return properly from `main()`, even if it's not technically required; 7. Have a function do a whole job, don't have it do half a job such that the caller has to complete the job after it returns.

Comment: 8. Compile with `-Wall -Werror`, 9. Use `strchr`: this function can be written in four lines of code.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths  Roger that!

Comment: Not sure what's "unclear" about "How can I move 1 through 4 to the loop part of the code?", seems like a pretty specific question to me.

Comment: I edited the title to specifically say that; hopefully someone with >3K rep will vote to reinstate your question.

Comment: An example of combining your current post-processing with a lookup-table implementation [can be found here](http://ideone.com/yrnuhF).

Comment: @WhozCraig - Your ideone implementation moves bytes multiple times.  Every time there's a character match, ALL of the characters that follow it are moved one byte down.... With large haystacks containing a lot of needles, you're looking at a lot of repetitive moves... In the worst case, it's something between O(n log n) and O(n^2).  All three of the working implementations in the two answers below move bytes from the source to the destination only once, regardless of how long the haystack is and how many needles exist in it.  Each of those implementations is O(n)......

Comment: ........However, if we could know up front that there would normally be only one needle in the haystack, your implementation would probably be faster in *that* case since memmove() is probably specialized/optimized for the target better than the compiler-generated code for any of the implementations in the two answers below.

Comment: @phonetagger I know. It was written in a bit of a hurry. The worst-case is an solid 0111111... pattern of things to keep vs. things to move, in which case it is definitely O(n^2) worst-case. I just didn't take the time to move a lower bound marker up such as is done in an in-place bottom-up quicksort partition algorithm. I really should go do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @phonetagger Ok. updated. I did kinda feel cheap for that post. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this isn't answering a homework question, but even if it is, I suppose since you already have a working solution I'm not technically doing anyone's homework for them.

Both of my solutions below implement collapse-in-place algorithms, which if applicable to the problem, is certaintly the most efficient approach.  If the problem requires a collapse-into-another-buffer solution, the modifications required would be minimal.  As mentioned by Paul Griffiths in his solution, the most efficient solution (for large haystacks) involves precomputing a lookup table of needle bools.  I've implemented such a solution in `mysqueeze3()` below.  Note that if the same set of needles would be used repeatedly, it would be better to split the function into two separate ones, one to initialize a needle array, and then the `mysqueeze` implementation would take a pointer to a needle array lookup table rather than a pointer to a string of characters.

In implementing any solution, you'd need to verify that it handles repeated needle characters correctly.  To test this, I extended your haystack string to sequences of four identical letters.  Your original post's solution handles this case correctly.  Both of my solutions also handle that case correctly.

It should probably be noted that though `mysqueeze3()` is more efficient than `mysqueeze2()`, the former is not a general solution, while the latter is.  The lookup table solution depends on a `char` being 8 bits in size (or smaller); i.e., there are at most 256 needle values.  If a `char` on your system is 9 bits or larger, that solution would need to be modified accordingly.  And if a `char` on your system is 16 bits or larger (perhaps unicode!), then the lookup table solution simply becomes impractical.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef enum {false=0, true=1} bool;
char *mysqueeze(char *a, char *b);
char *mysqueeze2(char *haystack, const char *needles);
char *mysqueeze3(char *haystack, const char *needles);
void mysqueeze_griffiths(const char * first, const char * second, char * result);

int main(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    char s1[100] = "kkkkrrrriiiisssshhhhnnnnaaaa";
    char s2[100] = "kareem";
    char real[100];
    char *t = mysqueeze(s1,s2);
    for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(t); i++)  //1
        if (t[i] != '*')
           real[j++] = t[i];
    real[j] = '\0';        //4

    printf("mysqueeze:           %s\n", real);

    char s3[100] = "kkkkrrrriiiisssshhhhnnnnaaaa";
    char s4[100] = "kareem";
    printf("mysqueeze2:          %s\n", mysqueeze2(s3,s4));

    char s5[100] = "kkkkrrrriiiisssshhhhnnnnaaaa";
    char s6[100] = "kareem";
    printf("mysqueeze3:          %s\n", mysqueeze3(s5,s6));

    char s7[100] = "kkkkrrrriiiisssshhhhnnnnaaaa";
    char s8[100] = "kareem";
    char result[100];
    mysqueeze_griffiths(s7,s8, result);
    printf("mysqueeze_griffiths: %s\n", result);

}

char *mysqueeze(char *a, char *b)
{
    int i = 0, k;
    do
    {
        k = 0;
        while (b[k] != '\0')
        {
            if (a[i] == b[k]) {
                a[i] = '*';
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (a[i]);
    return a;
}

void mysqueeze_griffiths(const char * first, const char * second, char * result) {
    while ( *first ) {
        bool found = false;
        while ( *second ) {
            if ( *first == *second++ ) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( !found ) {
            *result++ = *first;
        }
        ++first;
    }

    *result = '\0';
}

char *mysqueeze2(char *haystack, const char *needles)
{
    char *dest=haystack, *src=haystack;
    while (*src)
    {
        const char* n;
        for (n=needles; *n; ++n)
        {
            if (*n==*src)
            {
                ++src;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!*n)
           *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return haystack;
}

char *mysqueeze3(char *haystack, const char *needles)
{
    char *dest=haystack, *src=haystack;
    bool needleArray[256];
    memset(needleArray,0,sizeof(needleArray));
    for (const char* n=needles; *n; ++n)
        needleArray[(unsigned char)*n] = true;
    while (*src)
    {
        if (needleArray[(unsigned char)*src])
            ++src;
        else
           *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
    return haystack;
}
```

Comment: +1 You can generalize-out the worries about `char` size by using `bool needleArray[1 << CHAR_BIT];` Its there in limits.h, may as well use it for *something*. Nice writeup.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Thanks for the compliment.  BTW, I really wanna know who this "Craig" is....  Who ***is*** Craig?

Comment: @WhozCraig - AHH!  I checked your ideone solution and saw your casts of the lookup table indices...  I forgot about that... on systems where char is by default signed, my original mysqueeze3() would have failed in UB ways.  It's fixed now.... added the casts to (unsigned char).  As far as the generality added by using `1<<CHAR_BIT`.... Thanks, I hadn't thought about that.  But even with that, the lookup table solution is simply not suitable for systems where char's are >12 bits, as the table is just too large... unless all usable chars are all <9 bits and you limit the index accordingly.

Comment: Suitable is in the eye of the beholder. even at 16 bits you're talking about a static allocation of 64 KB, more than reasonable. Now, a char that is something like 24bits+, ok.. now we're into the realm of "ouch".

Comment: @WhozCraig - A stack allocation of 4KB or 64KB isn't really the issue.  As you say, 64KB on the stack isn't a big deal (esp. for desktop systems).  The real issue is that the whole lookup table needs to be initialized to all-zeros prior to setting the flags for all needles.  That adds a large amount of overhead for small haystacks.  For large haystacks, or if the lookup table is used (without re-initializing it) over & over again (by passing the lookup table into the squeeze function by reference), that cost could be amortized out.  If the lookup table is initialized each time, it can't be.

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer your question, the most obvious way to move 1 through 4 into your function is to pass `real` as a third argument. However, replacing the characters in `a` with `'*'` and then copying the others is an unnecessary step. Something like this is better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void mysqueeze(const char * first, const char * second, char * result);

int main(void) {
    char first[] = "krishna";
    char second[] = "kareem";
    char result[100];

    mysqueeze(first, second, result);

    printf("Result: %s\n", result);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void mysqueeze(const char * first, const char * second, char * result) {
    while ( *first ) {
        const char * t_second = second;
        bool found = false;
        while ( *t_second ) {
            if ( *first == *t_second++ ) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( !found ) {
            *result++ = *first;
        }
        ++first;
    }

    *result = '\0';
}
```

There are more time-efficient ways of implementing this algorithm, e.g. taking a single pass through the second string and setting a flag in an array for each character that is present, so each comparison with the first string can be done in a single constant-time lookup.

EDITED: Added variable `t_second` to respond to phonetagger's comment.

Comment: This solution does not correctly handle the case of consecutive repeating needle characters in the haystack.

Comment: @phonetagger: Ugh, not sure how I missed that, you're correct, I updated the answer.